# Using .append() in if statments?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to use .append() with if statements, I have a lot of them maybe 10. What I'm trying to do is add to a div if something happens. if A is less then 5 I want to add to the div, so on and so on. .append() works good for me if I put all of the things I want to add in one .append(). But if I try to do it separately it will not work for me. I don't know what I will be adding a head of time, it depends on user data so I can't add everything I want in one .append().   My code is long so I have put a fiddle below. I know i may have other issues with this code but, just asking about .append() or a way to add to my div like i want

```
if(k3a<5) {
    msg3="need to work on q3" 
    var c = $('<p>'+msg3+'</p>')
    $('#output1').append(c);
    $output1.text(msg3);
}
if(k4a<5) {
    msg4="need to work on q4" 
    var e = $('<p>'+msg4+'</p>')
    $('#output1').append(e);
    $output1.text(msg4);
}
if(k5a<5) {
    msg5="need to work on q5" 
    var e = $('<p>'+msg5+'</p>')
    $('#output1').append(e);
    $output1.text(msg5);
}
```

I know I can do something like below, but I need to add them one by one if the condition is meet, not at  once.

```
if (k1 < 10) {
    msg1 = "This will not space like a want.<br/>";
    msg2 = "I don know why not.<br/>";
    msg3 = "How come.<br/>";
    var e = $('<p>'+msg1+'</p>'+'<p>'+msg2+'</p>'+'<p>'+msg3+'</p>');
    $('#output1').append(e);
}
```

- http://jsfiddle.net/G24aQ/21/

Comment: just glancing through you are missing a bunch of semicolons

Comment: @Rooster semicolons are optional, preferred, but not necessary.

Comment: @user2537145 $output1 is not defined.

Comment: @Paul S.  ohhhhhhhh wow.  I should know that. :)

Comment: What exactly is not working? What are you expecting to happen and what happens instead? Exactly. How do we recreate the error?

Comment: sorry if you put in less the 5 in the all the inputs. and that should add the messages to the outbox. but i am only getting one message, instead of 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is `$output1`? That should be a variable, but you don't assign anything to it. Also, there is no need to use `$()` to put HTML into just for the sake of assigning it to your `c` or `e` variable. `$()` gets content. You just need to make a String, like:

```
var c = '<p>'+msg3+'</p>';
```

although I would have `var e, c` above all your code, if I was going to reuse it, so you don't have to rewrite `var`, and I wouldn't store `msg3` in a variable at all. My code would contain, something like:

```
var out1 = $('#output1');
if(k3a<5)out1.append('<p>need to work on q3</p>');
if(k4a<5)out1.append('<p>need to work on q4</p>');
if(k5a<5)out1.append('<p>need to work on q5</p>');
```

Your code is different on you jsFiddle page. For instance, `k3a` does not exist. Don't redefine `var total` in your code, either. There may be more problems with your code, but this should put you on the right path.

Comment: my code was working fine for me, the key word is me lol, but this was not working for me. I have more code i just tried to cut it down, this may even be something i had that was older, but same format. But i will take everyone advice and clean it up, still new so more worried about making something that works then doing it the best way possible.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like you don't understand what the code is doing; (assuming `$output1` is `$('#output1)`) current code is (just one part)

```
msg4="need to work on q4";    // set global variable `msg4`
var e = $('<p>'+msg4+'</p>'); // set local variable `e`
$('#output1').append(e);      // append html to element
$output1.text(msg4);          // re-set content of element as text
```

You most likely want just

```
var msg4="need to work on q4", // set local variable `msg4`
    e = $('<p>'+msg4+'</p>');  // set local variable `e`
$('#output1').append(e);       // append html to element
```

Comment: I think you're on the right track, just want to point out for the OP's sake that `var e = ...` is not even local to the if block, due to variable hoisting it's actually local to the whole click function handler. It really shouldn't be redefined at all.

Comment: Yes, only `let` supports using any `{ .. }` as a scoping block, `var` will go up to the parent _function_ or become global if there is no such _function_. (Off topic) This is one of the reasons I don't like seeing `for(var...`, that `var` is not scoped to the `for`.

Comment: for..get for loops. underscore js for life yo

Comment: @user2537145 You should only `var` each variable name **once** per function, and preferred in one `var` statement. `var a, b;` is okay, `var a; var b;` is okay, but `var a; var a;` is **not good**.

Comment: @Paul S. I thought it was what you where saying but did var e =' ' and took the var of the rest in the if's and don't work http://jsfiddle.net/G24aQ/23/

Comment: That isn't what my answer was about but a general piece of advice I added in comments.

Comment: Ok sorry I see! $output1.text(msg4); is the problem and should be var msg4 not msg4.

Answer (score 0):

you may find it easier to define a small function to output the messages. something like

```
function showMessage( strMsg, targetID ) {
    $('#'+targetID).empty().append("<p>" + strMsg + "</p>");
}
```

and call it using

```
showMessage( "message one", "output" );
showMessage( "message two", "output1" );
```

This way when you decide you want to display them in another fashion, you only have to change it in one place.